# Name of the art style in The Matrix

Tags: the-matrix, behind-the-scenes, art

I am always fascinated by the art style of the scenes in and around the derelict houses in the Matrix movies.

I know that in the computer game [Kingpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingpin:_Life_of_Crime), the surroundings look similar.

Is there a name for this style?

Comment: Can you add some pictures so we know what you're talking about?

Comment: The only similarity  I can see between Kingpin and the Matrix safehouses is that they're both run down urban environments.  I'm not aware of a name for it besides "reality".

Comment: Urban realism....

Comment: Urban decay would be my guess, but it really is just what American cities look like.

Comment: @WadCheber i'll add pictures when back at home. I have a friend that studies architecture, i'll try to get a quote from him.

Answer (score 4):

The film's [production designer](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/interview-with-production-designer-owen-paterson/#sthash.cpASABIw.dpbs) describes these sets as "*distressed*" and "*dilapidated*".

> **TheMatrix.com:** *It is impressive that they look aged.*
>
> **Owen:** *Yes, that is a cross over into various areas of the department. Peter Collias, the scenic artist, was pulled in to age a
>   lot of this stuff. With these sets we have a fortunate mix between
>   contemporary society, which is the glass and steel of the Matrix
>   world, and the world where the city has moved on, which the computer
>   is ignoring because it is irrelevant to this particular time frame in
>   the Matrix. It has a more dilapidated look, an aged look with rust and
>   peeling wallpaper. For a lot of our sets, like in the Lafayette Hotel,
>   we have had the opportunity to be able to distress the walls, carpets
>   and curtains so that everything within them feels like a rotting, wet,
>   urban, repulsive, maggotry.*

Answer (score 2):

What you're likely after is a sort of stylized urban decay, particularly with American urban architecture from the 1920s-40s, commonly found in big cities like New York or Chicago.

With the game Kingpin: Life of Crime, the art style was heavily influenced by the [Art Deco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_Deco) style which was also popular between the 1920s-40's.

The Matrix doesn't have the Art Deco stylings, but it certainly shares in the urban decay characteristics due to its [cyberpunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk) nature.

You can find similar examples of this stylized urban decay in movies like [The Crow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5uPZ7ocsqA), [The City of Lost Children](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0HWDOzi2h0), [Dark City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbFpLaytCv0), [Constantine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEa508Xmmio) and games like [Max Payne 1 & 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx1Ny3sAdew#t=34m15s) and [Deus Ex: Human Revolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx60cwMczPo&list=PLJA0MNUyOCaHoNj8NaCDj2Ygot-SDpLUj&index=13). For more Art Deco, check out Bioshock and Grim Fandango.

Fun Fact: the art director of Kingpin was Viktor Antonov who was also the art director for Half-Life 2 and Dishonored, so you may notice some similarities in the mixes of the alternative tech in these games as well as it being difficult to tell exactly what time/era they're supposed to take place.